# How to get the version number of a browser using Appium (Selenium Web-driver) with ruby

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm trying to get the version number of whatever version of Chrome is installed on the device i am performing mobile automated web testing on.

Currently i have:

```
desired_caps = {
    caps: {
        platformName: 'Android',
        versionNumber: '7.0',
        deviceName: 'S7 Edge',
        device: "Android",
        browserName: "Chrome"
    }
}

@driver = Appium::Driver.new(desired_caps).start_driver
@driver.get('https://www.google.com')
puts @driver.capabilities.version
```

But this returns an empty string. I understand there is a capability named 'version', but adding this to the capabilities like `version: 'latest'` just returns `'latest'` and not the version of Chrome which is installed on the device.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Chrome you could try to navigate to `chrome://version/` and parse the number:

```
driver.get("chrome://version/")
puts driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('td span').innerText")

> 62.0.3202.89
```

You could also get the version direcly from the [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent):

```
version = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent.match('Chrome/[^ ]+')[0]")
puts version

> Chrome/62.0.3202.89
```

Comment: Hi @Florent B. how would i also do this using the native browser?

Comment: @BIGJOHN, it depends on the browser, but you should be able to parse it from the user-agent.

Comment: is this the only way to get the browser version number when performing automated tests on mobile devices?